# Use number of misclassificatios as objective function for back propagation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, backpropagation

I'm new to machine learning (neutral network) and I have a question, please help me explain.
In back propagation, the objective function to be minimized is usually a sum of the squared error between the output and the target. However, in classification problems, the goal is often to minimize the total number of misclassifications. Why can this total number of misclassifications not be used directly as an objective function in back propagation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of mathematics. We'd really like to minimize number of misclassifications, but this target would be non-[smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness) (and not even [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)), and thus hard to optimize.

So, in order to optimize it, we use smooth "proxies": sum-of-squares penalizes your mistakes in a continuous way. Namely, a (very) tiny deviation in input parameters results in a tiny change of output. This would not be the case if non-continuous target function was used.

Also, note that to find a misclassification you need to compare output to the actual answer. Since you can't directly compare floating numbers for equality using `==`, you'll need to tolerate some errors. And, it's really not a big problem to miss answer by `0.001` when answers are of much bigger magnitude. So you want to push predictions as close to real answers as you can, and you do so by minimizing total distance from predictions to answers.

Comment: Very understandable answer,txs. And I'd like to add a thing: By using gradient descent on objective function (sum of squared error), we can adjust weight vector and finally find the acceptable values. For number of misclassifications, I don't think we can do like that.